# While loop not closing after defined in lambda

Tags: powershell, .net-core, aws-lambda

On occasion... I have an issue where the following while code does not close it's loop after it should close:

```
$cfn_stk_status = $null
$count = 0
while ($cfn_stk_status.StackStatus.Value -ne "CREATE_COMPLETE" -or $count -ne 10) {
    $cfn_stk_status = Get-CFNStack -StackName $cuurent_deployment -region $region 
    Write-Host "Deploying Stack $($cuurent_deployment) for Task: $($new_task) $($task_id) $count" $cfn_stk_status.StackStatus.Value
    Start-Sleep 10
    $count++
}
```

This does not happen every time. Correct me if I'm wrong, there's no reason that after the count hits 10 this should continue, correct? I cannot reproduce this so far on the command line. The $count will continue to iterate every 10 seconds until the lambda times out. If this is indeed a bug I'm wondering where the best place to post this issue would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a logic flaw in your `while` conditional; use `-and` instead of `-or`:

```
while (
  $cfn_stk_status.StackStatus.Value -ne "CREATE_COMPLETE" -and $count -ne 10
) { # ...
```

That way, the loop is exited once `$count` hits `10` *even if the status indicates that creation hasn't completed yet*.

With `-or`, the first `-ne` operation *alone* is sufficient to keep the loop going, so it will run for as long as the creation hasn't completed yet, irrespective of the `$count` value.

Comment: This does seem to make sense... i guess from the logs it takes a while for the while loop to catch up with the first statement then as the output shows a status of CREATE_COMPLETE until the count gets to 10. I guess that aligns if that and $count hit the desired values. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @TyMac.